# Erro ao tentar executar fwrite no PHP

Tags: php

Ao tentar executar o `fwrite` no PHP, recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> Notice: fwrite(): write of 24 bytes failed with errno=9 Bad file descriptor in C:\Apache24\htdocs\run-php\run.php on line 5

O código é o seguinte:

```
<?php

$arquivo = fopen('file.txt', 'r');

fwrite($arquivo, 'Conteúdo a ser inserido');

fclose($arquivo);
```

Qual é o motivo desse erro, como posso resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está usando o modo de leitura na função `fopen()` em vez do modo de escrita (em vez de `'r'` deveria usar `'w'`). Verifique os modos de acesso a um arquivo [na documentação oficial de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php#refsect1-function.fopen-parameters)

Comment: Obrigado, foi falta de atenção.